# How can I combine rows of data into a new table based on similar timestamps? (python/MySQL/PHP)

Tags: php, python, mysql, json, pingdom

Not sure if the title is a great way to word my actual problem and I apologize if this is too general of a question but I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around how to do something.

What I'm trying to do:
The idea is to create a MySQL database of 'outages' for the thousands of servers I'm responsible for monitoring. This would give a historical record of downtime and an easy way to retroactively tell what happened. The database will be queried by a fairly simple PHP form where one could browse these outages by date or server hostname etc.

What I have so far:
I have a python script that runs as a cron periodically to call the Pingdom API to get a list of current down alerts reported by the pingdom service. For each down alert, a row is inserted into a database containing a hostname, time stamp, pingdom check id, etc. I then have a simple php form that works fine to query for down alerts.

The problem:
What I have now is missing some important features and isn't quite what I'm looking for. Currently, querying this database would give me a simple list of down alerts like this:

Pindom alerts for Test_Check from 2012-05-01 to 2012-06-30:

test_check was reported DOWN at 2012-05-24 00:11:11
test_check was reported DOWN at 2012-05-24 00:17:28
test_check was reported DOWN at 2012-05-24 00:25:24
test_check was reported DOWN at 2012-05-24 00:25:48

What I would like instead is something like this:

test_check was reported down for 15 minutes (2012-05-24 00:11:11 to 2012-05-24 00:25:48)(link to comment on this outage)(link to info on this outage).

In this ideal end result, there would be one row containing a outage ID, hostname of the server pingdom is reporting down, the timestamp for when that box was reported down originally and the timestamp for when it was reported up again along with a 'comment' field I (and other admins) would use to add notes about this particular event after the fact. I'm not sure if I should try to do this when pulling the alerts from pingdom or if I should re-process the alerts after they're collected to populate the new table and I'm not quite sure how I would work out either of those options.

I'm a little lost as to how I will go about combining several down alerts that occur within a short period of time into a single 'outage' that would be inserted into a separate table in the existing MySQL database where individual down alerts are currently being stored. This would allow me to comment and add specific details for future reference and would generally make this thing a lot more usable. I'm not sure if I should try to do this when pulling the alerts from pingdom or if I should re-process the alerts after they're collected to populate the new table and I'm not quite sure how I would work out either of those options.

I've been wracking my brain trying to figure out how to do this. It seems like a simple concept but I'm a somewhat inexperienced programmer (I'm a Linux admin by profession) and I'm stumped at this point.

I'm looking for any thoughts, advice, examples or even just a more technical explanation of what I'm trying to do here to help point me in the right direction. I hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance for any advice :)

Answer (score 0):

The most basic solution with the setup you have now would be to:

- Get a list of all events, ordered by server ID and then by time of the event
- Loop through that list and record the start of a new event / end of an old event for your new database when:

  1. the server ID changes
  2. the time between the current event and the previous event from the same server is bigger than a certain threshold you set.
  3. Store the old event you were monitoring in your new database

The only complication I see, is that the next time you run the script, you need to make sure that you continue monitoring events that were still taking place at the time you last ran the script.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define the database schema that you like best from perspective of storing and querying outage data.  (Interval based.)
2. Define a stored procedure signature (parameters) that you like best from the perspective of recording Pindom events.  (Event based.)  Be sure to record also successful pings so that you can tell a long outage from two short ones.
3. Implement the procedure as specified.
4. Call the procedure after each ping.

The body of the procedure may roughly look like (pseudocode):

```
-- First, select the last interval as o1, and update it if the status is unchanged
UPDATE Interval SET ended = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM Interval AS o1 LEFT JOIN Interval o2 ON o2.ended > o1.ended
WHERE o2 IS NULL AND o1.status = @currentStatus

-- If the status changed, insert a new interval with the current status
IF ROW_COUNT() = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO Interval VALUES (...) 
END IF
```